# Someone bought bitcoins via hacking my PayPal account, how can I retrieve the bitcoins?

Tags: fraud, paypal, chargeback

Someone has been purchasing Bitcoins using my PayPal account - which was obviously hacked.  PayPal won't let me close the account yet.  I'm going to be charged NSF fees by my bank - I have the Bitcoin wallet address that the sale was made to: -

> Please confirm you want the Bitcoin deposited into Wallet: 1Jvgp9Qcr5D3K37gcfjsp4L5Csg8wwReye

I need to cancel that account, whoever it belongs to.

Comment: This is not a "tech support site".

Answer (score 6):

That is not possible.  By the decentralized design of Bitcoin, nobody has the ability to "cancel" the coins in an address held by someone else.

I'm sorry you were hacked, but it is almost certainly impossible to recover, block, or trace the funds at this point.

Answer (score 3):

you can claim a chargeback from paypal or open ticket to paypal saying you were hacked. Besides that there is nothing else you can do.

Comment: It should be noted that a chargeback may be possible to recover your fiat, but *not* take ownership of the bitcoin.